# ExpressionEngine 3 add back index.php through file

Tags: control-panel, htaccess, index.php

Did a little stupid thing the other day by removing index.php through control panel but not .htaccess. Now I can't access CP, and I need to add back index.php through the file, sort of manual way.

I'm developing locally and If I remove index.php through htaccess too it redirects to localhost:8888/admin.php

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
        RewriteEngine On
        RewriteBase /

        # Removes index.php from ExpressionEngine URLs
        RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET.*index\.php [NC]
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/system/.* [NC]
        RewriteRule (.*?)index\.php/*(.*) /$1$2 [R=301,NE,L]

        # Directs all EE web requests through the site index file
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
        RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

But because I have the site inside folders etc and have other projects I cannot have this site in root directory as localhost:8888

My current URL is http://localhost:8888/sitename/ee/admin.php

How can I turn back index.php but the manual way.

I hope this makes sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set, in your $config.php file

$config['index_page']           = "index.php";

That will override anything else that was previously set.